# Resolving service for IHttpClientFactory fails on Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to inject `IHttpClientFactory` service on Azure Function v3, but I keep getting the following erorr saying resolving a service failed.
I use azure-functions-core-tools@v3 to run Azure Function locally.

```
[2/14/2020 5:45:19 PM] Executed 'Foo' (Failed, Id=24489b3b-af99-417e-b175-443b76c241d5)
[2/14/2020 5:45:19 PM] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate 'MyFunction.Function.Foo'.
```

I have a startup class that is supposed to inject a service for `IHttpClientFactory`.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyFunction
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

And below is an azure function class that uses injected service of `IHttpClientFactory` to create a HTTP client and send a GET request to a server.

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunction.Function
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        public Scrape(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        }

        [FunctionName("Foo")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com");
            var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `startup.cs` class is missing it's assembly reference?

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunction.Startup))]
```

Try adding that to the startup class.  Add it just after your `using` statements at the top, and before any namespace declaration.

Also, most examples I have seen show the client actually created during function execution, not in the default constructor.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunction.Function
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        public Scrape(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            factory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        [FunctionName("Foo")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com");
            var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your example but I am still getting the same error. It's not that it is failing to creat http client, but it is failing to resolve a service of IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: Got it.  I'll post a startup.cs example too.  Quick note, I usually see an [assembly] reference in startup.cs and don't see that here.

Comment: This isn't the issue for me - all other DI is working (even HttpClient), just not IHttpClientFactory

Comment: Om found the issue - I still had builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IClass>() even though I changed the class to take IHttpClientFactory instead of HttpClient.  Can't seem to remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are two modes in which you can run your .NET class library functions: either in the same process as the Functions host runtime (in-process) or in an isolated worker process. In case of isolated-worker Program.cs file is the entry point for the app.

I was trying to inject HttpClient with Startup.cs but then got error "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate azure function"

For dependency injection at isolated-worker Azure Function use Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#dependency-injection)